# Nuxt serverMiddleware redirect is not a function

Tags: nuxt.js, middleware

I want to redirect in serverMiddleware for one route and it says redirect is not a function

code:

```js
export default function (req, res, next) {
  // req is the Node.js http request object
    const vuex = req.headers.cookie.slice(5);
    if (vuex.includes("auth%22:true")) {
        res.redirect(301, '/campaigns')
    }
    next()
}
```

I also tried using [res.writeHead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60261817/8344575) and it did not work as well. `res.writeHead` gives me this error message:
`Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` and if I put `next()` in else statement it says `The page isn’t redirecting properly`

code:

```js
export default function (req, res, next) {
  // req is the Node.js http request object
    const vuex = req.headers.cookie.slice(5);
    if (vuex.includes("auth%22:true")) {
        res.writeHead(301, {
          Location: '/campaigns'
        })
        res.end()
    } else {
        next()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to store the info from cookie to vuex first, then handle it in a server middleware

**store/index.js**

```js
const cookieFromRequest = (request, key) => {
    if (!request.headers.cookie) {
        return;
    }
    const cookie = request.headers.cookie.split(';').find(
        c => c.trim().startsWith(`${key}=`)
    );
    if (cookie) {
        return cookie.split('=')[1];
    }
}

export const actions = {
    nuxtServerInit({ commit, dispatch, route }, { req }){
        const token = cookieFromRequest(req, 'token');
        if (!!token) {
            commit('auth/setToken', token);
        }
    }
};
```

**store/auth.js**

```js
export const state = () => ({
    token: null
});

export const mutations = {
    setToken(state, token){
        state.token = token;
    }
}
```

then you can get the info from cookie in your middleware

```js
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
    const token = store.state.auth.token;
    if (!!token) {
        redirect('/campaigns');
    }
}
```