# Nuxt middleware to check if user is logged in not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to check if a user is authenticated and redirect them depending on the page they are in. for example if the user is logged in and they try to visit the login or signup page, they should be redirected. I have a middleware for that.

when I log in the user, the `authenticateUser` action runs and the user is created, when I check my cookies and local storage on the browser, I see that it is set correctly, but when I visit the login page after logging in, it doesn't redirect me.

middleware/altauth.js

```
export default function (context) {
    console.log(context.store.getters('profile/isAuthenticated'))
    if (context.store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
        context.redirect('/')
    }
}
```

also the token is both saved using Cookies and local storage and is persistence is through this middleware
middleware/checkauth.js

```
export default function (context) {
    if(context.hasOwnProperty('ssrContext')) {
        context.store.dispatch('profile/initAuth', context.ssrContext.req);
    } else {
        context.store.dispatch('profile/initAuth', null);
    }
}
```

and below are the values for my store

```
import Cookie from 'js-cookie';

export const state = () => ({
    token: null,
})

export const mutations = {
    setToken(state, token) {
        state.token = token
    },
    clearToken(state) {
        state.token = null
    }
}

export const actions = {
    async authenticateUser(vuexContext, authData) {
        let authUrl = 'https://look.herokuapp.com/signup/'
        if (authData.isLogin) {
            authUrl = 'https://look.herokuapp.com/login/'
        }

        return this.$axios
        .$post(authUrl, authData.form)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            const token = data.token
            vuexContext.commit('setToken', token)
            localStorage.setItem("token", token)
            Cookie.set('jwt', token);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
    },
    initAuth(vuexContext, req) {
        let token
        if (req) {
            if (!req.headers.cookie) {
                return;
            }
            const jwtCookie = req.headers.cookie
                .split(';')
                .find(c => c.trim().startsWith('jwt='));
            if (!jwtCookie) {
                return;
            }
            token = jwtCookie.split('=')[1];
        } else {
            token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            if (!token) {
                return;
            }
        }
        vuexContext.commit('setToken', token);
    }
}

export const getters = {
    isAuthenticated(state) {
        return state.token != null;
    },
}
```

please help, i don't know what the problem can be

Comment: do not use localstorge to store token, because the nodejs on your server side can't get it unless if you are running nuxt in SPA mode. store it into cookie. Also you may get the token from cookie in `nuxtServerInit`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67980994/nuxt-servermiddleware-redirect-is-not-a-function/67981443#67981443) may help. and for more about the full auth system in nuxt, [cretueusebiu/laravel-nuxt](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-nuxt) is a great example which can be helpful

Comment: do you run Nuxt in SSR mode or SPA mode?

Comment: Server Side Render mode, the thing is the course i followed it works perfectly in the SSR mode but when i try it, it saves to both the cookies and JWT but actually logging me in is still an issue @DengSihan

Comment: That's hard to guess. How did you call your altauth middleware in your login page?

Comment: @ßiansorÅ.Ålmerol i called the middle ware like this `middleware: ['check-auth', 'altauth'],`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic but full example for auth system in SSR nuxt

You will need two apis for this, one will return token info with user info, and the other will return user info only.

for example

```
POST http://example.com/api/auth/authorizations
{
    token: 'abcdefghijklmn',
    expired_at: 12345678,
    user: {
        name: 'Tom',
        is_admin: true
    }
}

// this need authed
GET http://example.com/api/auth/user
{
    name: 'Tom',
    is_admin: true
}
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
    plugins:[
        '~plugins/axios',
    ],
    buildModules: [
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
    ],
    router: {
        middleware: [
            'check-auth'
        ]
    },
```

**./pages/login.vue**

```js
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="login">
        <input type="text" name="username" v-model="form.username">
        <input type="password" name="password" v-model="form.password">
    </form>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
export default{
    data(){
        return {
            form: {username: '', password: ''}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        login(){
            this.$axios.post(`/auth/authorizations`, this.form)
                .then(({ data }) => {
                    let { user, token } = data;
                    this.$store.commit('auth/setToken', token);
                    this.$store.commit('auth/updateUser', user);
                    this.$router.push('/');
                })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**store/index.js**

```js
const cookieFromRequest = (request, key) => {
    if (!request.headers.cookie) {
        return;
    }
    const cookie = request.headers.cookie.split(';').find(
        c => c.trim().startsWith(`${key}=`)
    );
    if (cookie) {
        return cookie.split('=')[1];
    }
}
export const actions = {
    nuxtServerInit({ commit, dispatch, route }, { req }){
        const token = cookieFromRequest(req, 'token');
        if (!!token) {
            commit('auth/setToken', token);
        }
    }
};
```

**middleware/check-auth.js**

```js
export default async ({ $axios, store }) => {
    const token = store.getters['auth/token'];
    if (process.server) {
        if (token) {
            $axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
        } else {
            delete $axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
        }
    }
    if (!store.getters['auth/check'] && token) {
        await store.dispatch('auth/fetchUser');
    }
}
```

**store/auth.js**

```js
import Cookie from 'js-cookie';

export const state = () => ({
    user: null,
    token: null
});

export const getters = {
    user: state => state.user,
    token: state => state.token,
    check: state => state.user !== null
};

export const mutations = {
    setToken(state, token){
        state.token = token;
    },
    fetchUserSuccess(state, user){
        state.user = user;
    },
    fetchUserFailure(state){
        state.user = null;
    },
    logout(state){
        state.token = null;
        state.user = null;
    },
    updateUser(state, { user }){
        state.user = user;
    }
}

export const actions = {
    saveToken({ commit }, { token, remember }){
        commit('setToken', token);
        Cookie.set('token', token);
    },
    async fetchUser({ commit }){
        try{
            const { data } = await this.$axios.get('/auth/user');
            commit('fetchUserSuccess', data);
        }catch(e){
            Cookie.remove('token');
            commit('fetchUserFailure');
        }
    },
    updateUser({ commit }, payload){
        commit('updateUser', payload);
    },
    async logout({ commit }){
        try{
            await this.$axios.delete('/auth/authorizations');
        }catch(e){}
        Cookie.remove('token');
        commit('logout');
    }
}
```

**plugins/axios.js**

```js
export default ({ $axios, store  }) => {

    $axios.setBaseURL('http://example.com/api');

    const token = store.getters['auth/token'];
    if (token) {
        $axios.setToken(token, 'Bearer')
    }

    $axios.onResponseError(error => {
        const { status } = error.response || {};
        if (status === 401 && store.getters['auth/check']) {
            store.commit('auth/logout');
        }
        else{
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```

---

Then you can do what you want in your middleware, such as check auth

**middleware/auth.js**

```
export default function ({ store, redirect }){
    if (!store.getters['auth/check']) {
        return redirect(`/login`);
    }
}
```

Comment: bro, thanks so far, I just tried your code and it PARTIALLY works, the only thing is that the login isn't persistent because the cookie isn't set when I check in the browser. I believe that in the `./pages/login.vue` it was a commit that was made instead of a dispatch, i am not sure though.

Comment: @OpeyemiOdedeyi Sorry for that, you can reference [entir nuxt](https://github.com/DengSihan/bootstrap/tree/main/client), and also here is an online  [example](https://dancikuai.com/en) which using third part account to sign in, and the [code](https://github.com/DengSihan/dancikuai-front-end)

Comment: Bro, I want to thank you so much for all of your help, you are a great man. I appreciate the time you have helped me save and the problems I have solved with your  help.