# how to pass access_token from localStorage on graphQl request?

Tags: nuxt.js, apollo

I am trying to execute a query request

```js
# User is not authenticated error
    apollo:{
        users:{
            query:gql`
                query GetUsers{
                    users{
                        uuid
                        firstname
                        lastname
                        role
                    }
                }      
            `,
           
            getAuth: () => `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`,
        },

    },
```

before that I also tried to pass the token using context, but then the **LocalStorage is not defined error** appeared, as I understood this because the query is executed on the server side.

```js
#localStorage is not defined error
    apollo:{
        users:{
            query:gql`
                query GetUsers{
                    users{
                        uuid
                        firstname
                        lastname
                        role
                    }
                }      
            `,
            context() {
                    return {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
                        }
                    }
                
            },
            
        },

    },
```

how is the authorization token passing correctly done? Perhaps I do not understand something, I will be grateful for any help

Comment: LocalStorage is only accessible in browser (client side), you can't be able to do this in nodejs (UI server/backend). You may use cookie instead of  LocalStorage, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67980994/nuxt-servermiddleware-redirect-is-not-a-function/67981443#67981443) may help

Comment: @DengSihan thanks for the answer, but is it possible to somehow execute the query request from the client and not to

Comment: You could disable SSR for your nuxt project, then all the requests will be sent from clients' browser instead of your own server. Or send those requests in anywhere but `asyncData`/`fetch`/`store/index.js`

Comment: @DengSihan I solved the problem by specifying the prefetch parameter in the query request: false which indicates to make a request from the client